# APT upgrade fail2ban

Tags: ubuntu, apt, fail2ban

I am trying to update Fail2Ban to include more recent changes they've included (specifically, catching Apache's Primary Script Unknown) errors.

I am using Ubuntu 18 on a digital ocean droplet. When I try to apt-install, it is telling me that I already have the latest version, despite the facts that there are dozens of merged PRs in the repository that I don't have.

I run

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt dist-upgrade
apt install fail2ban
```

And get:

```
fail2ban is already the newest version (0.10.2-2).
```

If I run, `apt-cache policy fail2ban` it tells me that `0.10.2-2` is the version it has.

How can I get the latest version from `apt-get` without cloning directly from git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every application in Ubuntu will receive updates.

The update policy is explained [here](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle).

`apt-cache showpkg fail2ban` shows that `fail2ban` comes from the "universe" repository (extended open-source packages) and as such is not part of the base system and therefore has no maintenance commitment.

If you want an up-to-date version of you application, you have to do it outside of the Canonical repos:, which means, in decreasing easiness order:

- find a PPA that you add to your software sources (it's just and additional repo)(none for fail2ban)
- find a downloadable .deb that you can install with APT (none for fail2ban)
- install manually ([which seems to be the way](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban)).

As a side note, [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=fail2ban) shows that there won't be major upgrades of fail2ban if you get a more recent Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official package list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=fail2ban&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all), `0.10.2-2` is the latest version packaged for Ubuntu 18. Unless somebody provides a package e.g. using a [`ppa`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PPA) there is no way to install it with `apt install`